# Ionic 4 button disable on property

Tags: html, typescript, ionic4, angular8

I'm trying to disable a button on property with the [disabled] property in ion buttons, but the button doesn't enable with property value.

```
    <ion-button class="bottombtn" [disabled]="disable" expand="block" (click)="selectProperty()">
      {{this.pageContent.buttonText}}
    </ion-button>

  radioValue(value) {
    this.selectedAddress = value.detail;
    console.log(this.selectedAddress);
    this.disable = false;

  }
```

this radioValue function is working properly and changing the value as expected. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
<ion-button class="bottombtn" 
  [disabled]="(!selectedAddress || selectedAddress === '')" expand="block" 
  (click)="selectProperty()">
  {{this.pageContent.buttonText}}
</ion-button>
```

Comment: This will work if you don't check an array of addresses but only one address.

Comment: didn't work. had to create a click function on the radio button to alter the variable. weird.